# How do I copy a populated field, say a "company" name from one web page to another?

Tags: html

I want to copy (populated) data, say a "company" name from a form, to another form, and/or web page. This (populated) data field changes, based on what the client enters, however, the resulting data is always a "company".

Is there code I can paste into my HTML document to do this?

To better clarify what I want to do, please see as follows:

("To: ***_*__*_***")
This is on the top half of my web page in a word document contained in a form.

("Bandera") is the company name.
This is on the bottom half of my page in a word document contained in another form.

All I want to do is copy the "company" name (in this case Bandera) to the "To:***_*__**" on that form.

I only mentioned the fact that the company name "Bandera" changes, in case this has any affect on the issue.

I am not a programmer and do not know any languages, so I am looking for the easiest way (a code I can paste into my HTML document) to accomplish this.

Thank you,

Michael

Comment: This cannot be done using only HTML.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are trying to do. Maybe you could clarify your question a little bit?

Comment: Hi Oswald, yes, I Have two forms on the same web page. One of the forms is a Form List View of a "company". This "company" name changes, based on what the client selects from a previous page, so it is constantly changing. Whatever the resulting "company" name is, I would like to copy that "company" name, into another form on the same page. Basically I just want to copy "data" from one field in one form, to another form.

Comment: Hi Michael. Are you using ASP.Net?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't look like a problem with a simple cut and paste solution.  Since you haven't specified what technologies you're using, i'll keep it generic.  Two options that I see are:

1. Have the user submit the form, take the entered value on the server side and set it as a value/default in the resulting (your other) form that you return.
2. If you're just looking to populate another form on the same page, you can hook the onblur/onchange event of the input control with javascript and populate the value of a second form using something like the dom/javascript function GetElementById or GetElementByName.

Hope this helps point you in a useful direction.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are referring to a data-bound fields?
I am assuming further that the Company is populated from a database as an ID/Name hash/datatable.
If you are using ASP.Net, there a few options of which some are: storing your key for the data-bound field in Session, moving it across to another page using inline variables, or storing the selected Id against a user details table, and retrieving the ID on the other web-page.